# How to get the response data in @future(Callout=true)

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, future

I need to catch the response of a callout method and insert it into a database. But what the problem is, the callout method called from a trigger.

Therefore, I have to add the annotation `@future(Callout=true)`

```
   if( appStatusesBelowDocSent.contains(currentAppStatus) )
   {     
      envelopeId = EsignUtil.getEnvelopeId(app.Id);                                
      Docusign.voidEnvelopeAsync(envelopeId,'Application recalled or status is changed to a previous status');
      // TODO: I need to update a object with the response of Docusign.voidEnvelopeAsync  
   }
```

I can not insert the data inside the `voidEnvelopeAsync` in the same transaction with callout.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I got no errors. Just want to know, how to deal with this type of requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the results of an `@future` method in the currently running transaction (the transaction from which the asynchronous call is made). The `@future` method will not even execute until the current transaction completes and commits successfully (i.e., no unhandled exceptions leading to a rollback). There is no workaround; this is an inherent feature of the design of the Salesforce platform.

What you can do is restructure how you are building your functionality to work *with* the way Salesforce handles asynchronous operations. I'm not familiar with DocuSign, but I'll assume for the sake of illustration that you have access to a `Docusign.voidEnvelopeSync()` method that does the same callout synchronously.

If that's the case, you can write your *own* future method that calls that synchronous method and then takes action based upon the result:

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void doCallout(... parameters ...) {
    // do things ...
    // then:
    if (appStatusesBelowDocSent.contains(currentAppStatus)) {     
        envelopeId = EsignUtil.getEnvelopeId(app.Id);   
        // We're already in an async, callout-permitted environment,
        // so perform the action synchronously here.                             
        Object result = Docusign.voidEnvelopeSync(envelopeId,'Application recalled or status is changed to a previous status'); 

        // Perform DML to update related object.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Here is a similar question with some workarounds, maybe it will help you.

[Wait for Future Method execution before doing DML](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143835/wait-for-future-method-execution-before-doing-dml/143842)